# Publishing Azure Mobile App to Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, azureportal, azure-mobile-services

so i created my Azure Mobile App (Preview) project in visual studio, so just like Azure API App (preview) you can publish your project to azure by right clicking the project and click publish and you will see Azure API App Preview then you can now publish it to azure, but not in Azure Mobile app. so anyone who know how to publish it to azure? Please assume that I already created an Azure Mobile App in the portal and i just want to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I just need to select the Web App and i will see my Mobile App there. i use this reference 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/includes/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-publish-service.md